# Excel file with multiple tabs

Tags: ruby, excel, tabs

I need to create an excel file with multiple tabs. I need to do this in Ruby on Rails. I have checked out Apache POI but I'm not sure if it provides that functionality. Does anyone know if it does or if there are other alternatives that can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly - by multiple tabs you mean multiple 'worksheets' in a workbook. Apache POI does provide this functionality (check the links below). Please note that I am not a Ruby person (atleast not yet) and these links are for the usages in Java but I am pretty sure the bridges like YAJB will help you in getting it done:

[Creating a New WorkBook](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook)
[Creating a New WorkSheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewSheet)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you can call createSheet() on an instance of Workbook if you're using Apache POI.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ruby gem "spreadsheet-excel" for this kind of functionality

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
RAILS_ENV = 'production'

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'
require "spreadsheet/excel" 

file = "name_of_your_excel_file.xls" 
workbook = Spreadsheet::Excel.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/#{file}")

# First Sheet
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet No. 1")
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Timestamp")
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Type")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "Text")
# ...and whatever you want to do here
# Second Sheet
worksheet_2 = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet No. 2")
#... and so on
```

This works great both in Ruby and Ruby-on-Rails.

To install spreadsheet/excel just type

```
ruby gem install "spreadsheet-excel"
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tab excel sheet using spreadsheet gem

To create multiple sheets in a single excel sheet , its good to use spreadsheet gem. In your controller (suppose card is your controller) add the following:

def export

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Sheet1'
sheet2 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Sheet2'

 sheet1.row(0).push "some content in Column1" //to push content in 1st row 1st column of 1st spreadsheet

 //keep pushing on row(0) if you want to push contents other columns of 1st row

  spreadsheet = StringIO.new
  book.write spreadsheet
  file = "Excelsheet"
  send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "#{file}", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

end

In you view
<%=link_to("Export Database to Excel", cards_url + "/export")  %>**strong text**